# Pytorch Multi-GPU Training Error: CUDA error: CUDA-capable device(s) is/are busy or unavailable

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I am currently trying to train an object detector implemented in Pytorch on multiple GPUs using `DistributedDataParallel` and I start the main with `torch.multiprocessing.spawn`. When calling `DistributedDataParallel` I get the error:

```
-- Process 1 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 69, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/ user/MA/code_copy/masterarbei/src/faster_rcnn/faster_rcnn_v1_parallel.py", line 178, in main_initial_train
    model = DDP(model, device_ids=[rank])
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 674, in __init__
    _verify_param_shape_across_processes(self.process_group, parameters)
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/utils.py", line 118, in _verify_param_shape_across_processes
    return dist._verify_params_across_processes(process_group, tensors, logger)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUDA-capable device(s) is/are busy or unavailable
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

At `spawn`, the number of available GPUs (`wordlist`) is set with:

```
world_size = torch.cuda.device_count()
```

So all GPUs should be available. Does anyone know what the problem could be or how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance!